# Python not evaluating statement, just printing

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which holds multiple entries.
e.g. I have `response[0]['values']['id']` and `response[2]['values']['id']`.

`response[0]` has no key `'id'` whereas `response[2]` does.

I'm looping through the responses but everytime I try and evaluate
`response[0]['values']['id']` it just prints `'id'`.  Even if I try `if (response[0]['values']['id'])` or `type(response[0]['values']['id'])`, it does not evaluate the statement but just prints `'id'`.

```py
response = requests.get (......get command)

test = type((response[0]['value']['id']))

print(test) # 'id'
```

The statement is not being evaluated and it don't give me the value.

Anyone know why?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you please include the code you are running? It it is long, you can include the part you are having the problem.

Comment: Hi, can;t provide full code due to it being internal api keys used

Comment: Ok. Just include parts of it that you are printing things and the loop. Don't include any important data like api keys. You can omit the important parts and just keep the loop.

Comment: added more info in edit! thanks

Comment: Why are you using `type` function in your code?

Comment: it's just any statement to see if it evaluates

Answer (score 0):

maybe a different conditional statement like searching through the dict keys will work

`if ('id' in response[0]['values'].keys()): print(response[0]['values']['id'])`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding except Keyerror!